# EMR, Spark: proper place for a local shared cache

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, caching, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

In our Spark application, we store the local application cache in `/mnt/yarn/app-cache/` directory, which is shared between app containers on the same ec2 instance

`/mnt/...` is chosen because it is a fast NVMe SSD on r5d instances

This approach worked well for several years on EMR 5.x - `/mnt/yarn` belongs to the `yarn` user, and apps containers run from `yarn`, and it can create directories

In EMR 6.x things changed - containers now run from the `hadoop` user which does not have write access to `/mnt/yarn/`

`hadoop` user can create directories in `/mnt/`, but `yarn` can not, and I want to keep compatibility - the app should be able to run successfully on both EMR 5.x and 6.x

`java.io.tmpdir` also doesn't work - it is different for each container

What should be the proper place to store cache on NVMe SSD (`/mnt`, `/mnt1`) so it can be accessible by all containers and can be operable on both EMR 5.x and 6.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your EMR cluster, you can add the `yarn` user to the super user group; by default, this group is called `supergroup`. You can confirm if this is the right group by checking the `dfs.permissions.superusergroup` in the `hdfs-site.xml` file.

You could also try modifying the following HDFS properties (in the file named above): `dfs.permissions.enabled` or `dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm`.

Comment: thanks, it seems that such manual folder management is the only way